# Centering elements of a site using flexbox (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how do I move my elements to a specific position please? I would like the same layout as this site and for that I used flexbox, except that the elements are not positioned in the same way as the model: https://hermesbot.app/
The text, the logo, the footer, and the icons don't move to the right place
Of course it must remain responsive so I don't know how to do it but I'm trying to use % to make it responsive, is it a good idea ?

I attach my code so you can answer my questions. Thanks in advance.

If you see any other concerns I'd love to hear them, as this is a rather complex project for me

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 span {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #221616;
}

body {
  background: #26372b;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg,#1c271f,#221616);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body h1 {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 2.488rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.image_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;
  left: -32px;
  max-width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}




footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot</title>
    <meta name="title" content="Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot">
    <meta name="description"
        content="Poseidon is intended for users who do not want to bother to have 20 bots on their server, simplify your life today by inviting it on your server!">

    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://metatags.io/">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot">
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="Poseidon is intended for users who do not want to bother to have 20 bots on their server, simplify your life today by inviting it on your server!">
    <meta property="og:image"
        content="https://metatags.io/assets/meta-tags-16a33a6a8531e519cc0936fbba0ad904e52d35f34a46c97a2c9f6f7dd7d336f2.png">

    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://metatags.io/">
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot">
    <meta property="twitter:description"
        content="Poseidon is intended for users who do not want to bother to have 20 bots on their server, simplify your life today by inviting it on your server!">
    <meta property="twitter:image"
        content="https://metatags.io/assets/meta-tags-16a33a6a8531e519cc0936fbba0ad904e52d35f34a46c97a2c9f6f7dd7d336f2.png">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="branding">
            <h1>
                <span>The future of</span>
                <span class="highlight">your discord bot</span>
                <span>is on the way !</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/PoseidonBotApp"> <img class="icon" src="img/twitter.svg"
                    alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/poseidon"> <img class="icon" src="img/discord.svg" alt="Discord Logo"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/PoseidonBotApp"> <img class="icon" src="img/github.svg" alt="Github Logo"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>



    <div class="image_container">
        <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" href="index.html">
    </div>

    <footer>
        &#169; Copyright Centaure-Studio Made with love by
        <a href="https://antyss77.com/">Antyss77</a>
    </footer>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1st thing, if you are making something response, stay away from absolute and relative positioning

Comment: Thank you but I don't know what to replace it with

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the same website you mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1):

`body` can also be a flexbox and `.container` be centering itself on both axis  via `margin:auto;`:

```css
/* update to code ================== */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  /* reset */
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  /* see me if no src avalaible */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: gray;
  /* end demo css */
  /* position and coodonate not needed , margin can be used */
  margin:auto 1em;
}


/* end update ====================== */

h1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin:0;
}

h1 span {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #221616;
}

body {
  background: #26372b;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, #1c271f, #221616);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /*height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;*/
  /* not sure these are needed */
}

.icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding:0
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body h1 {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 2.488rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.image_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  max-width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot</title>
  <meta name="title" content="Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot">
  <meta name="description" content="Poseidon is intended for users who do not want to bother to have 20 bots on their server, simplify your life today by inviting it on your server!">

  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://metatags.io/">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Poseidon is intended for users who do not want to bother to have 20 bots on their server, simplify your life today by inviting it on your server!">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://metatags.io/assets/meta-tags-16a33a6a8531e519cc0936fbba0ad904e52d35f34a46c97a2c9f6f7dd7d336f2.png">

  <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://metatags.io/">
  <meta property="twitter:title" content="Poseidon — The Perfect Discord Bot">
  <meta property="twitter:description" content="Poseidon is intended for users who do not want to bother to have 20 bots on their server, simplify your life today by inviting it on your server!">
  <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://metatags.io/assets/meta-tags-16a33a6a8531e519cc0936fbba0ad904e52d35f34a46c97a2c9f6f7dd7d336f2.png">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="branding">
      <h1>
        <span>The future of</span>
        <span class="highlight">your discord bot</span>
        <span>is on the way !</span>
      </h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/PoseidonBotApp"> <img class="icon" src="img/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="https://discord.gg/poseidon"> <img class="icon" src="img/discord.svg" alt="Discord Logo"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="https://github.com/PoseidonBotApp"> <img class="icon" src="img/github.svg" alt="Github Logo"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="image_container">
      <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" href="index.html">
    </div>

  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/PoseidonBotApp"> <img class="icon" src="img/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="https://discord.gg/poseidon"> <img class="icon" src="img/discord.svg" alt="Discord Logo"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="https://github.com/PoseidonBotApp"> <img class="icon" src="img/github.svg" alt="Github Logo"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>





  <footer>
    &#169; Copyright Centaure-Studio Made with love by
    <a href="https://antyss77.com/">Antyss77</a>
  </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I had tried what you said but here is the result: https://i.imgur.com/qmNKPDx.png so I had deleted and left as on the code I sent

Comment: if the logo needs to be aside the text , move it to the same container, allow that container to wrap if screen is too small . snippet updated

Comment: Like that?   https://i.imgur.com/JPVsyEq.png

Comment: nop aside .branding so it is a direct child of your flex box .container  ;) Look at the snippet . If that is what you try to do

Comment: Ah yes thank you I had not seen so much for me it's really that the layout is almost perfect, but how to move the icons, and lower the footer please? and more up the person says I should not use the positions, but how to replace them so that the whole site is responsive please?

Comment: test the snippet again, and see how it behaves. flexbox and alignement via justify-content/align-items or margin from the child will do the job instead position. flex-wrap will allow title and logo to wrap on top of each others.

Comment: I tested yes but that's what I'm telling you is that the icons and the image are not well positioned

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/s1K1ZMe.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234512/discussion-between-kalypsotek-and-g-cyrillus).